# Can i use orm entites with SonataDoctrinePhpcrAdminBundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-sonata, symfony-cmf

How to start using orm enites with Sonata-Admin-bundle if alredy use SonataDoctrinePhpcrAdminBundle ?

This is possible ?

my composer.json

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "dev-master",
    "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-jackrabbit": "1.0.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal":"dev-master",
    "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "liip/functional-test-bundle": "dev-master",
    "lunetics/locale-bundle": "dev-master",
    "liip/doctrine-cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "symfony-cmf/content-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-extra-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony-cmf/routing": "1.1.*@dev",
    "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*"
},
```

I spent a few days in the search for solutions and fixing most errors.
Some one use Symfony-cmf in production ?Or symfony-cmf not ready now for this segment ?

Will there be a better solution to use only Sonata bundles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle) for your entities. The [SonataDoctrinePhpcrAdminBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrinePhpcrAdminBundle) will only work with documents managed by the doctrine-phpcrodm project.
It is very much possible to use the two bundles and corresponding backend system side by side so you can mix orm and phpcrodm admins in the same application.